# Python - printing lists with special characters

Tags: python

I have a question regarding printing lists

I have small code:

```
list=[]
var='Value\'1'
list.append(var)
print(list)
```

The output of print(list) is presented in quotes:

```
["Value'1"]
```

My question is - could I force python to print it in apostrophes(') instead of quotes(")?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do with the output? Why do you need it in single quotes instead of double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

don't use reserve words like `list`. *(I change `list` to `lst`)*:

```
print("['{}']".format(*lst))
# ['Value'1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print("['{}']".format(', '.join(list)))
['Value'1']
```

or If you do not want any quotes

```
>>> print("[{}]".format(', '.join(list)))
[Value'1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `print(list)` is dependent on the [list.__str__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [list.__str__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) methods. If you want to change the representation of the list, you would have to override that method.

FYI, it is generally not a good idea to override the names of build-in types like `list` or `str`, since that makes it more difficult to initialize new lists (and can make things harder to read)

Here's an example that forces it to use single quotes on the outside:

```py
class MyStr(str):
    def __repr__(self):
        output = self.replace("'", "\\'")
        return "'"+output+"'"

mylist = [MyStr("Value'1")]
print(mylist)
```